# How can I show an Icon and a String in a JList in Java?

Tags: java, swing, model, jlist

I have a class Test whose field can be changed in the program when selected in a JList.
I've tried:

```
model = new DefaultListModel();
list = new JList(model);
model.addElement(new Test(1.0f));
```

but then I get Test@44322 in my JList.
I want a black square and the String "Test" in my JList.
What's the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach is quite OK, next step is to tell the list how to render an object Test, i.e.

```
list.setCellRenderer(...)
```

my 0.02€